# How to convert List to a JSON Object using GSON?

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I have a List which I need to convert into JSON Object using GSON. My JSON Object has JSON Array in it.

```
public class DataResponse {

    private List<ClientResponse> apps;

    // getters and setters

    public static class ClientResponse {
        private double mean;
        private double deviation;
        private int code;
        private String pack;
        private int version;

        // getters and setters
    }
}
```

Below is my code in which I need to convert my List to JSON Object which has JSON Array in it -

```
public void marshal(Object response) {

    List<DataResponse.ClientResponse> clientResponse = ((DataResponse) response).getClientResponse();

    // now how do I convert clientResponse list to JSON Object which has JSON Array in it using GSON?

    // String jsonObject = ??
}
```

As of now, I only have two items in List - So I need my JSON Object like this -

```
{  
   "apps":[  
      {  
         "mean":1.2,
         "deviation":1.3
         "code":100,
         "pack":"hello",
         "version":1
      },
      {  
         "mean":1.5,
         "deviation":1.1
         "code":200,
         "pack":"world",
         "version":2
      }
   ]
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The JSON you have shown is not a JSON array it is a JSON object.

Comment: oops sorry, yes it is JSON Object. Let me rephrase the question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If `response` in your `marshal` method is a `DataResponse`, then that's what you should be serializing.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(response);
```

That will give you the JSON output you are looking for.

Answer (score 91):

There is a sample from google gson [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples) on how to actually convert the list to json string:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
 List<String> target = new LinkedList<String>();
 target.add("blah");

 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
 List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

You need to set the type of list in `toJson` method and pass the list object to convert it to json string or vice versa.

Comment: This is unnecessary and won't produce the JSON they asked for.

Comment: This won't create any key name for json. How to create a key name as OP expected?

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you also want to get json in format

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "mean": 1.2,
      "deviation": 1.3,
      "code": 100,
      "pack": "hello",
      "version": 1
    },
    {
      "mean": 1.5,
      "deviation": 1.1,
      "code": 200,
      "pack": "world",
      "version": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

instead of

```
{"apps":[{"mean":1.2,"deviation":1.3,"code":100,"pack":"hello","version":1},{"mean":1.5,"deviation":1.1,"code":200,"pack":"world","version":2}]}
```

you can use *pretty printing*. To do so use

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(dataResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to convert your collection to an Array first:

```
Gson().toJson(objectsList.toTypedArray(), Array<CustomObject>::class.java)
```

Answer (score -4):

We can also use another workaround by first creating an array of myObject then convert them into list.

```
final Optional<List<MyObject>> sortInput = Optional.ofNullable(jsonArgument)
                .map(jsonArgument -> GSON.toJson(jsonArgument, ArrayList.class))
                .map(gson -> GSON.fromJson(gson, MyObject[].class))
                .map(myObjectArray -> Arrays.asList(myObjectArray));
```

Benifits:

- we are not using reflection here. :)