# Save an array to sharedpreferences and show it in listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I need to save user input to shared preferences and also show it from shared preferences in a listview. How can I do this?

Right now my code adds to listview, but does not save it.

```
ListView listView;
Button AddWebsiteBtn;
EditText WebsiteName;
String[] ListOfWebsites = new String[]{};
SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_websites);
    AddWebsiteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    WebsiteName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.website_name);

    //using this part to add it to listview, maybe will need to remove it when shared preferences will work
    final List< String > ListElementsArrayList = new ArrayList< String >
            (Arrays.asList(ListOfWebsites));

    final ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter< String >
            (AddActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    ListElementsArrayList);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    AddWebsiteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ListElementsArrayList.add(WebsiteName.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For doing this , what issue are you getting ?

Comment: I'm not getting any issue, the problem is I have no idea how to store users input to shared preferences and how to retrieve it and show it in listview

Comment: Do you want to store only single String or list of same type of string , What are the contents of your list ?

Comment: Single string per list line.
Example:
So user has 1 input field, he writes Bob saves it, and it's displayed in a list:
Bob . 

Then he writes Josh and saves it, and now in List its displaye like this:
Bob
Josh

Comment: It means you have list and you want to show your list from Sharepreferences & also you want to edit and save

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to store all of your list item to `ArrayList` then Store `ArrayList` to `SharedPreference`

Variable declaration

```
SharedPreferences shared;
ArrayList<String> arrPackage;
```

Variable Initialization :

```
  shared = getSharedPreferences("App_settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
 // add values for your ArrayList any where...
 arrPackage = new ArrayList<>();
```

.Store value to `sharedPreference` :

```
 private void packagesharedPreferences() {
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
   Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
   set.addAll(arrPackage);
   editor.putStringSet("DATE_LIST", set);
   editor.apply();
   Log.d("storesharedPreferences",""+set);
   }
```

Retrive value of `sharedPreference`:

```
 private void retriveSharedValue() {
   Set<String> set = shared.getStringSet("DATE_LIST", null);
   arrPackage.addAll(set);
   Log.d("retrivesharedPreferences",""+set);
 }
```

Comment: THANK YOU, took some time to figure it out how to implement it to my code (but that's because I'm new to Java and Android studio) but it works!!!

Comment: Happy to help you, Do your coding , if you got any issue comment here @AlgirdasŽarkaitis

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for serializing your Array to `JSON String` so you can store it in SharedPreferences as usual `String`.

GSON examples you can find in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893342/how-to-convert-list-to-a-json-object-using-gson)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your array of strings into a comma separate value (csv) string and save it. Use `String.join(",", new String[]{"A", "B"});` in Java 1.8

When retrieving take is as a string and convert back to String array. use `yourString.split(",")`