# Save dynamic ListView in SharedPreferences using Gson

Tags: android, listview

I have a dynamically grown ListView. It's like a simple to-do-list app. The user inputs a string, the string is added to the listView. The data in the listView can be deleted by using the delete button. Nothing special at all. The problem is that this listView is gone when you close the app by pressing the back button. 
I now discovered gson to save my listView and to retrive it later.

Unfortunately I have some understanding problems. First, this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public SharedPreferences pref;
public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
EditText editText;

Context context;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ImageButton imageButtondelete;
TextView textViewAdd;
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<String> arrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.todolist);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    textViewAdd = findViewById(R.id.textViewAdd);
    imageButtondelete = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    initListView();
    text2List();
    deleteItemsinListView();
}
    // init the listview
public void initListView() {
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("");

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, arrayList);
    adapter.remove("");
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // when checked, strike through the data in the list
            if (listView.isItemChecked(position)) {
                TextView text = (TextView) view;
                text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            } else {
                TextView text = (TextView) view;
                text.setPaintFlags(0);
            }
       }
    });
}
// add user input from edittext to the list
public void text2List() {
    textViewAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()))
                // this line adds the data of your EditText and puts in your array
                arrayList.add(editText.getText().toString());
            // next thing you have to do is check if your adapter has changed
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            editText.getText().clear();
        }
    });
}

public void deleteItemsinListView() {
    imageButtondelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.clear();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Now, I read this article [How to convert List to a JSON Object using GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893342/how-to-convert-list-to-a-json-object-using-gson) and the not accepted but valid answer is

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
 List<String> target = new LinkedList<String>();
 target.add("blah");
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
 List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

How can I apply the first line of this code snippet to my Listview? I can't see a way.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use GSON? I can show you a very simple, 2 lines of code way using the org.json library, to convert anything into a json string.

Comment: @Daniel B. Can you Show me how to save my list at all ? Gson is not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using org.json

You can use the org.json library instead of using GSON

Use it like this:

```
private void test(){
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strings);
        String stringTosave = jsonArray.toString();
    }
```

Here is the link to download the library:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813

The file is located under the **Files** row.

## Saving to SharedPreferences

To save the String in SharedPreferences, get a reference to your SharedPreferences Editor, using `Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();`

then use `editor.putString("yourkey",stringToSave);`

when you are done putting strings , you need to call `editor.commit()`, to save your changes.

to retreive use `getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("yourkey");`

## Full example

```
  private void test(){
      List<String> strings = new ArrayList();
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strings);
      String stringTosave = jsonArray.toString();

      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
      editor.putString("key","string");
      editor.commit();

      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String saved = sharedPreferences.getString("key","defaultvalue");
      JSONArray savedJsonArray = new JSONArray(saved);
    }
```

Comment: Ok I see thank you but how to save this now ? And retrieve it later

Comment: @Blnpwr edited to show you how to save the string to SharedPrefernces.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask you questions if they occur ?

Comment: @Blnpwr sure. Also i edited the answer to use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` to convert the list to a string, because a list is a collection, and you should use `JSONArray` for collections.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it and will eventually write you.

Comment: So 2 questions: 1: I think it should be `editor.putString("key", stringTosave);` right? Second question: When I want to retrive my data from SharedPreferences do I have to put the logic in `onPause` ?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. You can use it whenever you want, there are no restrictions to when you can use it

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. It worked finally. Is there a way to stay in touch with you?