# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I  am facing this error while I am posting a json array to server using retrofit. My json is valid as I checked the same by an online tool
Here is my json that I am posting

```
[
  {
  "image":"/9j/4AAQ//Z",
  "pole_code":"Adv234",
  "latitude":28.62628851,
  "longitude":77.37868293,
  "vendor_name":"1"
  }
]
```

And the here is the method for posting the same

```
@POST("SyncPole")
Call<SyncApiResponse>uploadSurveyData(@Body JsonArray array);
```

Code for making JsonArray

```
private JsonArray createJsonArray(List<PoleSurveyData> list){
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    if (list != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            try {
                String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(list.get(i).getImage(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP);
                jsonObject.addProperty("image", imgString);
                jsonObject.addProperty("pole_code", list.get(i).getPoleCode());
                jsonObject.addProperty("latitude", list.get(i).getLatitude());
                jsonObject.addProperty("longitude", list.get(i).getLongitude());
                jsonObject.addProperty("vendor_name","1");

                jsonArray.add(jsonObject);

                ;

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
}
return jsonArray;
}
```

I have followed these links ["Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1) but none of them is working 
Screen shot of postman request
[image]
Can someone help me out where I am doing wrong

Comment: your json starts with `[` and ends with `}` which is wrong

Comment: @pz64_ that was a posting mistake what now

Comment: You are getting this exception because your API call is not execute successfully or API response is not in correct structure to be parsed.  the possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1

Comment: @JakirHossain but the same I am able to send via postman

Comment: if you're trying to make json string out of the dataclass, why don't you do it with gson. Actually, it does that for you, no looping and stuff . Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/27893385/6737471

Comment: @pz64_ still I am getting the same error

Comment: can you share the new code

Comment: @JakirHossain I have added postman screen shot

Comment: @JakirHossain You are right , I have made my backend developer to change the response in proper structure Now its Working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"success"
```

You are getting `String` in `Response` but you expecting an `object` of `SyncApiResponse`. that's the problem

**Solution:** you have to change the response format. like the following structure.

```
{
 "status": "success",
 "message": "demo message"
}
```